# How do you contain a nuclear explosion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, material-science, radiation, explosions, nuclear-engineering

What properties would a material need to contain a nuclear explosion (I'll go with the Tsar Bomba) such that it has no effect on outside conditions. For specificity I'll go with:

- Ultimate tensile strength
- Melting point (Not sure if the definitions get shady here since well it gets pretty 'ionisingly' hot)
- Radiation absorption
- We'll leave it as a 10m diameter sphere with a thickness of 1m
- Any other relevant information

And yes, I am very well aware that this material probably does not exist.

Comment: Depends a lot on how big the container is. Lots of underground tests were contained just fine.

Comment: @JonCuster I've adjusted the question for specificity

Comment: It also depends on how small the bomb is. [Is it possible securely detonate a hydrogen bomb inside a very, very thick iron armor to get the armor only rise its temperature and not break apart?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681109/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 I chose the Tsar Bomba

Comment: There are such things as containment buildings or vessels for nuclear reactors but they are of course for containment of chemical explosions. They are normally large, strong and either cylindrical or better still (for efficiency) spherical. If you want to contain a massive thermonuclear blast I am quite sure that 1m thick structural steel and 10m diameter would be hopelessly weak. I don't know if anyone is going to do the calculation for you.

Comment: Convert megatons of yield to eV. Estimate number of atoms in your shell. Divide to get eV per atom. Realize you need unobtainium.

Comment: Having just quickly run those numbers, a 150MT yield provides more than 55keV per atom of the vessel. I believe that puts the material requirements well past unobtainium into the realm of complete and utter fantasy...

Answer (score 3):

At the temperatures of a hydrogen bomb explosion, all known elements will melt and explode into vapor, and the pressures associated with those temperatures are sufficient to blow any enclosure to pieces no matter what it is made of, in your example. Read Richard Serber's book *The Los Alamos Primer* for details on temperatures and pressures.

To date, the only way to "contain" an *atomic explosion* is to bury the bomb under a very deep layer of earth and rock, as was done during the bomb tests in the USA during the 1950's-60's. Even then, the hundreds of thousands of tons of rock surrounding the explosion was pushed outward, leaving a large hollow subterranean sphere behind- which sometimes then caved in on itself.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @niels nielsen is correct; a massive overlay of earth with no fissure flaws is necessary for nuclear weapons with significant yield as in the nuclear arsenals of weapons-states.  No reasonably sized metal container can withstand the pressure /temperature from the detonation. Suggest you look at discussions of underground nuclear tests at the Nevada Test Site on-line for more specifics; such as horizontal tests, vertical tests, containment designs, etc.

One challenge of the underground tests is the containment design; specifically, to allow radiation from the detonation of the weapon to be detected by instruments at a line-of-sight distance from the "working point" (the nuclear explosive), then to close off the line-of sight from debris to prevent destruction of the instrumentation.  Special very fast closing vault type doors and grouting materials were used for this. Also, the geology of the surrounding medium is important.  Initially after the detonation, the ground buckles up, and later after the underground material has cooled the bubble collapses into a crater.  The Neveda Test Site has numerous pot-marks, the craters from prior tests.  During the era of underground tests, numerous geologists and "containment" scientists/engineers were involved in the test/earth containment design to "ensure" the containment of radioactive debris from the tests.

Comment: The (freely available) publication, "Caging the Dragon" (DOE NV-338) can be found using standard search engines.

Comment: This is a wonderful reference, thanks so much!  I remember Carl Keller and Joe Lacomb, two of the many containment experts included in this report.

Comment: The containment group is still active, but deals with much lower output energy experiments than it used to...